# Find the particular first and last index in vector<float> C++

Tags: c++

I have a vector of wavelengths, min and max wavelength value. 
Using these max and min value I need to find the valid indexes in the vector of wavelength which is inside this range and put those values in a WavelengthArray.

for example :

i have a vector of wavelengths starting from (200 to 900), total wavelengths are 2048 but I need to find the wavelengths between the min(for example 300) and maximum (800) and put them in an array. 
But I need the first Index and last Index from the vector of wavelengths too as I will need to put the data corresponding to these wavelengths as well.

```
std::vector<double> vDoubles(p_sWavelangth.begin(), p_sWavelangth.end());
int firstIndex,lastIndex;
double WavelengthArray[2048];

for (int index = 0; index < p_sWavelangth.size(); index++) {
    if (p_sWavelangth[index] >= wmin) {
        firstIndex = index;
        break;
    }
    else if (p_sWavelangth[index] >= wmax) {
        lastIndex = index-1;
        break;
    }
}
```

How to get this right ?

Comment: Your post appears to be missing a detailed description of the problem you are having and is missing a [mcve].

Comment: added some information

Comment: and what exactly is going wrong with the code you provided?

Comment: Its not giving me the firstIndex and lastIndex

Comment: It should give at least first index correctly. the problem is with the break

Comment: how can I get the last index and all the wavelengths in an array.

Comment: `double smallest = std::min_element(300.00, 700.00, p_sWavelangth);
  double largest = std::max_element(300.00, 700.00, p_sWavelangth);`

Comment: tried this for getting the min and max value from  the vector but its giving alot of errors

Comment: @PSDebugger -- the `min_element` and `max_element` functions do not return the value.  They return an iterator to the value.  That's probably where you are getting your errors, and that is by not [reading the docs carefully](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)

Comment: I suggest you to carefully think through the iteration process you written) Your cycle breaks after min is found - and it shouldn't

Comment: Can you please help. I am struck on this :(

Comment: @PSDebugger -- First, are these items sorted?  If so, doing a linear search is not optimal when you could use `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: yes these are sorted.

Comment: they are all double values for example from 201.2, 201.5 etc but the min will be 300 and max will be 700 ( for example)

Comment: Also `std::find_if` can be used

Comment: Hint: Google: "Binary Search" and "overloading operator less than" and "std::lower_bound"

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is sorted, you don't need to do a linear search for the items as you're doing now.  Using algorithm functions such as [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) will do a binary search for the data, which is much more efficient if you have many items to search.

```
#include <algorithm> 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float test[] =  { 1, 2, 3, 199, 300, 301, 690, 799, 1000, 1100};
    float *pFirst = std::lower_bound(std::begin(test), std::end(test), 200);
    float *pLast = std::prev(std::lower_bound(std::begin(test), std::end(test), 800));
    std::cout << *pFirst << " " << *pLast << "\n";

    // Now get the index
    auto index1 = std::distance(test, pFirst);
    auto index2 = std::distance(test, pLast);
    std::cout << index1 << " " << index2;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4aa15d52f77a135)

[Live Example using vector](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f55b88b457835ab)

Comment: giving me errors as I have data in `std::vector<float> p_sWavelangth` and min max in double.
`static void set_wavelengths2(double wmin, double wmax, std::vector<float> p_sWavelangth)`

Comment: Take the example at the link, compile it, run it, understand it.  The errors you're describing have nothing to do with properly calling `lower_bound`.  Are you using a C++ 11 compliant compiler?

Comment: Some work, googling, and understanding may be required before cut and pasting into homework :)

Comment: @PSDebugger -- I added an example using vector.  Same principle applies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that cycle breaks right after min index is found.

Straightforward way to fix your code is - match max index after min index is found instead of break.

Your code will transform into something like this:

```
bool min_found = false;
for (int index = 0; index < p_sWavelangth.size(); index++) {
    if (!min_found && p_sWavelangth[index] >= wmin) {
        firstIndex = index;
        min_found = true;
    }
    else if (min_found && p_sWavelangth[index] >= wmax) {
        lastIndex = index-1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not a good or an optimal solution to the problem. This should not be done brute force and anyone would get kicked out of an interview for doing it that way.

Comment: I used a word 'straightforward' to describe the solution. Assuming author of the question is aware of the complexity of the code given in question - this approach may work as well for a particular use case. Point of my answer is to show mistakes in *given* code.